# Does the size of a pointer to a structure increase as memory is allocated for that structure?

Tags: c, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
  typedef struct
  {
  int length ;
  int * data ;
  } Array ;
```

And in my main function I do the following:

```
 int length = 10;
 char * filename = " data ";
 // create an object
 Array * arrptr1 = NULL ;
 printf (" sizeof ( arrptr1 ) = % d \ n ", ( int ) sizeof ( arrptr1 ));
 arrptr1 = malloc ( sizeof ( Array ));
 printf (" sizeof ( arrptr1 ) = %d , sizeof ( Array ) = % d \ n" ,
 ( int ) sizeof ( arrptr1 ) , ( int ) sizeof ( Array ));
 // allocate memory for the data
 arrptr1 -> length = length ;
 arrptr1 -> data = malloc ( sizeof ( int ) * ( arrptr1 -> length ));
 printf (" sizeof ( arrptr1 ) = %d , sizeof ( arrptr1 -> data ) = % d \ n " ,
 ( int ) sizeof ( arrptr1 ) , ( int ) sizeof ( arrptr1 -> data ));
```

What would be printed for each of the print statements?

I know for the first print, `sizeof(arrptr1)` would just be a garbage value.

For the second print, would `sizeof(arrptr1)` = 8 and `sizeof(Array)` = 8 as well?

What would the third print statement output?

Comment: The size of the pointer won't change but I think you are asking about the size of the contents that the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: `sizeof(some_pointer_variable_or_type)` returns the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to.

Comment: The pointer contains the address of the first byte of the structure. Why would the pointer size increase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know for the first print, sizeof(arrptr1) would just be a garbage value.

No, it will be the size of the pointer. If, for example, it's a 64-bit platform where all pointers are 8 bytes, it will print 8. If it didn't give you a sensible value, how could you know how much memory to allocate to store an instance of the type?

> For the second print, would sizeof(arrptr1) = 8 and sizeof(Array) = 8 as well?

Not likely. Since an `Array` has an integer and a pointer, it will likely by 16 bytes on platforms with 8 byte pointers and 4 byte integers. (If it was 12 bytes, an array of `Array`s would have every other element unaligned.)

> What would the third print statement output?

It is a common beginner mistake to think that `sizeof` cares what is in the things whose sizes you ask it about. It just gives the size of the relevant types.

```
char * j;
sizeof(j);    // equivalent to sizeof(char*)
sizeof(*j);   // equivalent to sizeof(char)

j = "hello";
sizeof(j);    // still equivalent to sizeof(char*)
sizeof(*j);   // still equivalent to sizeof(char)

j = malloc(32);
sizeof(j);    // still equivalent to sizeof(char*)
sizeof(*j);   // still equivalent to sizeof(char)
```

You can think of `sizeof` as telling you how many characters you would need to hold an instance of the type of its parameter.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake for the first one.  Thank you for the clear explanation and example for the other two.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(arrptr1)` and `sizeof(arrptr1->data)` are both the size of a pointer. A pointer is a variable that holds an address. All addresses* are the same size. So these will always print the same value.

A variable has the same size whether it's been initialized or not.

`sizeof(Array)` will return the size of an `Array`, consisting of an `int` and a pointer - which is most likely 8 or 12, or 16 if you have an 8-byte pointer *and* the compiler decides to insert some padding.

* (I believe function addresses are allowed to be a different size from non-function addresses, but you aren't using any function pointers here)

Comment: "All addresses* are the same size" -> not really.  It is common that pointers to functions have a different size than object pointers - as you noted.  C supports all sorts of different size pointers `int*`, `char*`, etc. even on the same platform.